# How to scale data when creating a new geom in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a new `geom` in `ggplot2` which draws a lot of lines. However, my problem is that lines drawn were not accurate. Here is a simple illustration of my problem. Consider this example

```
GeomLine1 <- ggproto("GeomLine1", Geom,
                       required_aes = c('x','y'),
                       default_aes = aes(colour = "black"),
                       draw_key = draw_key_abline,

                       draw_panel = function(data, panel_scales, coord) {

                             grid::linesGrob(x=data$x,y=data$y,default.units = 'native')}
)

geom_line1 <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
                          position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                          inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
      layer(
            geom = GeomLine1, mapping = mapping,  data = data, stat = stat,
            position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
            params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
      )
}
```

This is a new a geom called `geom_line1` which should draw a line.

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(0,10), y = c(0,10))

ggplot(dat,aes(x,y))+geom_line1() + geom_point()
```

Output Of this CODE is

[image]

You can see the line is extending beyond the points at that position. If I use default function `geom_line`, It is perfect. What is wrong in my code ? Also, It will be great if anyone can suggest good tutorial for writing new geoms.

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x,y))+geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: [Tutorial](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html).

Comment: @Axeman I have read that no luck. Thanks

Comment: Did you compare your `geom_line1` with the source for `geom_line`?

Comment: `geom_line` uses `GeomPath` which uses `segmentsGrob` or `polylineGrob`, not `linesGrob`, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Even with `segmentsGrob` or `polylineGrob` it is still like that

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to figure out the problem. Actually we have to use transform the data like this and use transformed data for plotting.

```
coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_scales)
grid::linesGrob(x=coords$x,y=coords$y,default.units = 'native')
```

Instead of `data$x` and `data$y` we should coords$x and coords$y